# Migrate Plone users and groups to relational data

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I have a Plone 4 site which contains a lot of users and groups which are stored in the ZODB.  Over time, we added some functionality which uses relational data (in a PostgreSQL database); some tables have fields which contain user or group ids.

However, currently the users and groups are defined in ZODB rather than the RDB, so we don't have proper foreign keys here.  Thus, the obvious idea is to migrate the user and groups data to the RDB - those who/which are used by the Plone site, at least; I assume emergency users need to be an exception to this (but those are no members of any groups anyway).

Would this be a good thing to do?

Are there reasons to do it only partly, or should I transfer everything including group memberships?  (Since memberships are stored as lists of users (and/or groups) with the containing group, I could imagine a reverse table which holds all groups a user is member of, and which is maintained by a trigger function.)

Are there any special tools to use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imho it's based on what you want to achieve. In Plone you have [PAS](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.PluggableAuthService), so technically it doesn't really matter, where you put users, groups and user group relationships.

You can store users/groups in:

- Plone (by default)
- SQL - [pas.plugins.sqlalchemy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pas.plugins.sqlalchemy/0.3)
- LDAP/AD - [Products.PloneLDAP](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.PloneLDAP/1.2)

There are also many other plugins for AUTH, like RPX, Goolge+, etc.

You can enable, disable and modify the behabvior of every plugin thru PAS.

**Does it make sense, to NOT use Plone users?**

Of course, if you want to share user credentials (Example LDAP), or if you need the user informations in other Apps, etc.

**Migration**

Should be very simple if the PAS plugins you are using supports "Properties" and "User enumeration".

Get the data from one plugin and put the data into another one with a simple python script. Both supports the same API.

Comment: I think the SQLAlchemy solution is my best option, thank you. I hope I'll be able to configure the database name in my buildout, so I can have a local replication of an instance with an independent RDB without using the ZMI every time ...

Answer (score 1):

the tool you're looking for is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pas.plugins.sqlalchemy/0.3

I've used this in a webportal where users are "shared" with a newsletter system.
I've 200 users and any problem.

I think the only "good reason" to store users in an external DB rather in zodb/plone is in a use-case like mine.

Have you ever think about "extend" plone users (ex. https://plone.org/products/collective.examples.userdata)? With plone.api you can easly manipulate users' properties in your code.

Comment: Another *good reason* is if you refer to user and group ids in relational tables, as in my case ... Easy manipulation of the user schema is nice, but in my case, at lot of silly programming has been done because of lacking relational access to user and groups data.